# Interfacing not being Implemented correctly

Tags: java, interface, queue, implementation

I created two files, one with the interface as follows:

```
       public interface ICharQ {
       void put(char ch);
       char get();
       }
```

and the implementation classes as follows:

```
    //A fixed size Queue class for characters

    class FixedQueue implements ICharQ{
    private char q[]; //This queue holds the characters
    private int putloc, getloc; //the put and get indices

    public FixedQueue(int size){
    q = new char[size+1]; //allocate memory for the queue
    putloc = getloc = 0;
}

    //Put a character into the queue
    public void put(char ch){
    if(putloc == q.length - 1){
    System.out.println(" - Queue is full");
    return;
    }
    putloc++;
    q[putloc] = ch;
}

    //Get a character from the Queue
    public char get(){
    if(getloc == putloc){
    System.out.println(" - Queue is empty");
    return (char) 0;
    }
    getloc++;
    return q[getloc];
}
}

    //A circular Queue
    class CircularQueue implements ICharQ{
    private char q[]; //This queue holds the characters
    private int putloc, getloc; //the put and get indices

    public CircularQueue(int size){
    q = new char[size+1]; //allocate memory for the queue
    putloc = getloc = 0;
}

    //Put a character into the queue
    public void put(char ch){
    /*Queue is full if putloc is one less than getloc or if putloc is at the    end and getloc is at the beginning */
    if((putloc + 1 == getloc)|(putloc == q.length-1 & getloc == 0)){
    System.out.println(" - Queue is full");
    return;
    }
    putloc++;
    if(putloc == q.length) putloc = 0; //reset loop
    q[putloc] = ch;
}

    //Get character from the Queue
    public char get(){
    if(getloc == putloc){
    System.out.println(" - Queue is empty");
    return (char) 0;
    }
    getloc++;
    if(getloc == q.length) getloc = 0;
    return q[getloc];
}
}


    //A dynamic Queue
    class DynQueue implements ICharQ {
    private char q[]; // this array holds the queue
    private int putloc, getloc; // the put and get indices
    // Construct an empty queue given its size.
    public DynQueue(int size) {
    q = new char[size+1]; // allocate memory for queue
    putloc = getloc = 0;
}

    //put a character into the queue
    public void put(char ch){
    if(putloc == q.length-1){
    //increase queue size
    char t[] = new char[q.length * 2];

    //copy elements into the new queue
    for(int i=0; i<q.length; i++)
    t[i] = q[i];
    q = t;
    }
    putloc++;
    q[putloc] = ch;
}

// Get a character from the queue.
    public char get() {
    if(getloc == putloc) {
    System.out.println(" – Queue is empty.");
    return (char) 0;
    }
    getloc++;
    return q[getloc];
}
    }

    //Demonstrate the ICharQ interface
    class IQDemo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    FixedQueue q1 = new FixedQueue(10);
    DynQueue q2 = new DynQueue(5);
    CircularQueue q3 = new CircularQueue(10);

    ICharQ iQ;
    char ch;
    int i;

    iQ = q1;
    //Put some characters into the fixed queue
    for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
    iQ.put((char)('A' + i));
    }
    //Show the queue
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    System.out.print("Contents of fixed queue: ");
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    ch = iQ.get();
    System.out.print(ch);
    }
    }
    System.out.println();
    iQ = q2;
    // Put some characters into dynamic queue.
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
    iQ.put((char) ('Z' - i));
    // Show the queue.
    System.out.print("Contents of dynamic queue: ");
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    ch = iQ.get();
    System.out.print(ch);
    }
    System.out.println();
    iQ = q3;
    // Put some characters into circular queue.
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
    iQ.put((char) ('A' + i));
    // Show the queue.
    System.out.print("Contents of circular queue: ");
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    ch = iQ.get();
    System.out.print(ch);
    }
    System.out.println();

    // Put more characters into circular queue.
    for(i=10; i < 20; i++)
    iQ.put((char) ('A' + i));
    // Show the queue.
    System.out.print("Contents of circular queue: ");
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    ch = iQ.get();
    System.out.print(ch);
    }
    System.out.println("\nStore and consume from" +
    " circular queue.");
    // Use and consume from circular queue.
    for(i=0; i < 20; i++) {
    iQ.put((char) ('A' + i));
    ch = iQ.get();
    System.out.print(ch);
    }
}
}
```

Now the files are in the same directory. The ICharQ.java file compiles just fine. But when I am trying to compile the IQDemo.java it gives out error stating it cannot find ICharQ.

However when i remove the public accessor from interface file and include the code in IQDemo, it works perfectly. But the moment i change it to public it is not compiling.

Is there something wrong with the code or am i missing out somehting? Kindly help please.

Comment: What if you compile them at the same time? Also, which packages are they in? The default package is a bad place to keep anything.

Comment: Is the current directory "." included in your classpath?

Comment: @Kayaman The second file is not compiling. IT says it cannot find the ICharQ symbol. They are in a separate directory under one package. Please help.

Comment: @Jesper I can add classpath only when I run it. but the implementation file is not compiling itself.

Comment: @Chatterjee 
I tested in my system it is working correctly. Is following is your expected output? 
`Contents of fixed queue: ABCDEFGHIJ

Contents of dynamic queue: ZYXWVUTSRQ

Contents of circular queue: ABCDEFGHIJ

Contents of circular queue: KLMNOPQRST

Store and consume from circular queue.

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST`

Comment: @KalathokiYup, thats the desired output. Its coming for me with default accessor..but the moment i change the interface accessor to public, it doesnt compile.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with paths and packages. Check your classpath settings (`cp` commandline option), make sure you declare the package at the top of each file and that those files are placed in filesystem accordingly.

You should have something like `package YourNick.YourProject;` as the first line of both your files. Then you compile them using `javac -cp $CP $CP/YourNick/YourProject/{ICharQ,IQDemo}.java` and the resulting bytecode files (namely `ICharQ.class` and `IQDemo.class`) should be created in `$CP/YourNick/YourProject`. Then you execute the `java` command as `java -cp $CP YourNick.YourProject.IQDemo`.

When using an IDE, classpath settings and directory structure of the project are handled somehow automatically. Still you have to choose a package name.

So, this should be the result (shown as a shell session):

```
$ cd /home/chatterjee/java-projects
$ ls Queue
ICharQ.java    IQDemo.java
$ cat Queue/ICharQ.java
package Queue;
public interface ICharQ {
    void put(char ch);
    char get();
}
$ cat Queue/IQDemo.java
package Queue;
… lots of code …
$ javac -cp . ./Queue/{ICharQ,IQDemo}.java
$ ls Queue
ICharQ.class    ICharQ.java    IQDemo.class    IQDemo.java
$ java -cp . Queue.IQDemo
… desired output …
```

Comment: The problem is actually the second file IQDemo.java is not compiling. They are both in the same package Queue. here is the error for one implementing class -                 
IQDemo.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol: class ICharQ
                class FixedQueue implements ICharQ{

Comment: @S.Chatterjee If they're in the same package, are they in the same directory?

Comment: the package name is Queue. so should i compile like:  javac -cp $CP $CP/Queue/{ICharQ,IQDemo}.java ?

Comment: @S. Chatterjee: Assuming you set the CP variable to something like `/home/chatterjee/java-projects`, yes. Compiler needs to know where to look for the interface when compiling IQDemo.java. This info is supplied by the `-cp` option.

Comment: @Palec Tried that sir, but not working somehow. Has it got something to do the accessor? It is running on default accessor, but not on public.

Comment: @S. Chatterjee: You have to use the `public` access modifier for an interface or a class when you want to access it from other source files. And vice versa, at least in Java – if you declare an interface or a class public, they must be in their own file (along with their non-public helper classes and interfaces).